# How to set an entity as a Navigation Property (Get) and also be able to pass a complex object into it (Patch, Put)

Tags: odata

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and OData. I have a model A with several nav properties to other models, for example, model B. For a Get, I want to be able to call A, and Expand to B (I can do this successfully). The tricky bit is that now I want to be able to call Patch, and inside the body, include all the data for A as well as the nested data for B.

I know that EF does not accept data in virtuals, so I figured I could pull that data our in my application and null out those fields manually before saving with EF. That would be great.

However, the only way I can get OData to accept my subobject is by specifying that the type of the property B is a complex object, by adding this line to the model builder...

```
builder.ComplexType<B>();
```

I can then pass in nested data of this type on Patch, but now my Get doesn't work, because it says you can't expand to complex types, only navigational types.

So, it only works one way or the other. Any ideas on how I can accomplish something like this for both situations at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$ref` to set up the link between entities.

For example:

1. `POST ~/As` to create a new `A` to `As`, from the response, you can get the location Id. So, you can get the key of new `A`
2. `POST ~/Bs` to create a new `B` to `Bs`, from the response, you can get the location Id. So, you can get the id (uri) of new `B`.
3. Then, you can use the `$ref` to create a link between the new `A` and the new `B`.
   For the $ref, you can refer to the sample code [here](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/blob/409a6b059a6b4ce8e2ab3c2eeffefe4e6e451158/WebApiODataSample/WebApiODataSample/Program.cs#L64-L88).